# Error deserializing json with nested arrays

Tags: json, .net-core, razor-pages

I'm trying to deserialize a json object that includes nested arrays and I get the following error when I try it in Postman:

> {
> "errors": {
> "accounts": [
> "Cannot deserialize the current JSON array (e.g. [1,2,3]) into type 'Orders.Dtos.Accounts' because the type requires a JSON object (e.g. {"name":"value"}) to deserialize correctly.\r\nTo fix this error either change the JSON to a JSON object (e.g. {"name":"value"}) or change the deserialized type to an array or a type that implements a collection interface (e.g. ICollection, IList) like List that can be deserialized from a JSON array. JsonArrayAttribute can also be added to the type to force it to deserialize from a JSON array.\r\nPath 'accounts', line 7, position 17."
> ]
> },
> "type": "https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc7231#section-6.5.1",
> "title": "One or more validation errors occurred.",
> "status": 400,
> "traceId": "00-92466567188264cbdc71e6f6d7479688-fe08150cd947ddf1-00"
> }

Simplified json to deserialize:

```
{
   "plannedShippingDateAndTime": "2023-02-07T07:06:00 GMT+01:00",
   "pickup": {
       "isRequested": false
   },
   "productCode": "N",
   "accounts": [
       {
           "typeCode": "shipper",
           "number": "999999999"
       }
   ]
```

}

Classes:

```
public class ShipmentData
{
    public string PlannedShippingDateAndTime { get; set; }
    public Pickup Pickup { get; set; }
    public string ProductCode { get; set; } = "N";
    public Accounts Accounts { get; set; }
}

public class Pickup
{
    public bool isRequested { get; set; }
}

public class Accounts
{
    public ArrayAccounts[] ArrayAccounts { get; set; }
}

public class ArrayAccounts
{
    public string TypeCode { get; set; }
    public string Number { get; set; }
}
```

Api Controller:

```
[HttpPost("CreateShipment/{OrderId}")]
public async Task<ActionResult> CreateShipment(string OrderId, ShipMentData shipmentData)
{
    ...
}
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```
public class ShipmentData
{
    public string PlannedShippingDateAndTime { get; set; }
    public Pickup Pickup { get; set; }
    public string ProductCode { get; set; }
    public Account[] Accounts { get; set; }
}

public class Pickup
{
    public bool IsRequested { get; set; }
}

public class Account
{
    public string TypeCode { get; set; }
    public string Number { get; set; }
}
```

Also [Customize JSON binding](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/minimal-apis?view=aspnetcore-7.0#customize-json-binding):

```
options.SerializerOptions.PropertyNamingPolicy = JsonNamingPolicy.CamelCase;
```